# redirectURL maps to the RequestMapping("/") in controller but I want it to map it to RequestMapping("/abcd") because I have react SPA which handles it

Tags: oauth, openid, openid-connect, okta

I have OpenID implemented for Okta with all the required details like clientid, secretid, authorization URL and all with redirectURL. It maps to the RequestMapping("/") in controller but I want it to map it to RequestMapping("/abcd") because I have react single page application which handles the root url mapping ("/") and starts the React app, if Java controller has RequestMapping("/"), the it doesn't open the react page

--

Here in this example https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect

I have implemented for the authentication provider other than google.
I have a front end react app loading the root mapping but if I add controller mapping ("/") then the react app doesn't load because I have handled the root mapping on controller. All I want is I want to pass the token to the react app how can i do that?????

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
  public ModelAndView index(ModelMap attributes) {
    Map<String, String> userData = OpenIdConnectFilter.userInfoData;
    org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken 
 oAuth2AccessToken = OpenIdConnectFilter.accessTokenData;
    openIdUserDetailsMapper.createUserFromOpenIdToken(userData);
    final String username = 
 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    attributes.addAttribute("accessToken", 
oAuth2AccessToken.toString());

    return new ModelAndView("index", attributes);
 }
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and show your [mcve]. Tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, show the results.

Comment: Here in this example https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect

I have implemented for the authentication provider other than google.

Comment: All I want is I have an access token and I want to send this token to the react single page application. ------- Please help....